# Understanding flutter design elements material colours in text fields

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter so please bare with me and my ulgly code here. I am trying to create a login screen and so far I have the following.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Text('Login Page '),
      ),
      body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Text(
                    'The Hockey Lab',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        fontSize: 30),
                  )),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: nameController,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 0.0),
                    ),
                    border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
                    labelText: 'User Name',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
                child: TextField(
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  obscureText: true,
                  controller: passwordController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
                    labelText: 'Password',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  //forgot password screen
                },
                textColor: Colors.blue,
                child: Text('Forgot Password'),
              ),
              Container(
                  height: 50,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Text('Login'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => AdminMenuPage()),
                      );
                      print(passwordController.text);
                    },
                  )),
              Container(
                  child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Does not have account?'),
                  FlatButton(
                    textColor: Colors.blue,
                    child: Text(
                      'Sign in',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      //signup screen
                    },
                  )
                ],
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              ))
            ],
          )));
  }
}
```

Which is producing me this Gui however I have an issue When I first load the app I get this

[image]

But I want the both textboxes to be white all the time with the frames but when I take my mouse away it disappears I presume its another colour I need like a not focussed colour, also you will notice the username bit has disapeared from the text field widget?.

Also does flutter have such a thing as place holder text color?

[image]

I am evuluating flutter for front end stuff at min as Maui is pushed back another six months and I just want to see how long takes me to do the same app in flutter.

Comment: Do you have an expected UI image? Have you tried setting `InputDecoration`'s `fillColor: Colors.white,` and `filled: true,`?

Answer (score 0):

you need just to set the color of the `container` that contain the `textField` like this :

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    foregroundColor: Colors.white,
    title: Text('Login Page '),
  ),
  body: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Text(
                'The Hockey Lab',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    fontSize: 30),
              )),
          Container(
            color: Colors.White, // here set the color you want
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: TextField(
              controller: nameController,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 0.0),
                ),
                border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
                labelText: 'User Name',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.White, // here set the color you want
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
            child: TextField(
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              obscureText: true,
              controller: passwordController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
                labelText: 'Password',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              //forgot password screen
            },
            textColor: Colors.blue,
            child: Text('Forgot Password'),
          ),
          Container(
              height: 50,
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                textColor: Colors.white,
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Text('Login'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => AdminMenuPage()),
                  );
                  print(passwordController.text);
                },
              )),
          Container(
              child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Does not have account?'),
              FlatButton(
                textColor: Colors.blue,
                child: Text(
                  'Sign in',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  //signup screen
                },
              )
            ],
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          ))
        ],
      )));
}
}
```

Comment: Thats wrong cause its sets the full container white including edges i only want the frame to be white of the text field when its not focused

Comment: the aswer was updated, hope this helpful @csharpdude77